# Two dimentional array as ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build multiple-choice-question(MCQ) app in angularjs. I have following data.

```
var questions = [
            {
                questionId: 1,
                question: 'Can I build this app with angular',
                answer: 'yes',
                options: ['yes','no','depends','may be']
            },
            {
                questionId: 2,
                question: 'Is earth is flat',
                answer: 'no',
                options: ['yes','no','don\'t know']
            }
]
```

**My index.html looks like this**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <p>question: {{ question.question }}</p>

    <div data-ng-repeat="option in question.options">
        <label data-ng-class="{correct-ans: answer[$parent.question.questionId][$index] == $parent.question.answer}">
            <input type="radio" data-ng-model="answer[$parent.question.questionId][$index]" name="{{ 'option'+$parent.question.questionId }}" value="{{ option }}"/>{{ option }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to **apply the css class correct-ans** to the label when user choose the correct answer. The above code is throwing **TypeError** cannot set 'some value' to undefined.
then I tried to define a $scope variable *$scope.answer = [[],[]]*, but now it only works for 1st question only after that again TypeError shows up. Plz assist me how to do this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you setup a Plunkr to help you better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type error appeared because ng-model tried to set something to $scope.answer[questionId][optionId] and get undefined. When you defined $scope.answer = [[],[]] it works fine for first question only because its questionId == 1, and $scope.answer[1](http://jsfiddle.net/GRaAL/d9Jaj/) refers to the **second** element of answer array (as arrays indexes are started from 0). For second question it tried to access $scope.answer[2] which does not exist.

I'm not sure you really need the 2-dimensions array here - what you need is to store what user answered for each question, compare with valid answer and highlight corresponding option if it was selected. I'd like to suggest having this code instead:

```
//javascript
$scope.answer = [];
$scope.isCorrectAnswer = function(question, option) {
    return option == question.answer && $scope.answer[question.questionId] == option;
} 

//html
<div data-ng-repeat="option in question.options">
    <label data-ng-class="{'correct-ans': isCorrectAnswer(question, option)}">
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="answer[question.questionId]" name="{{ 'option'+question.questionId }}" value="{{ option }}"/>{{ option }}
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GRaAL/d9Jaj/).

Comment: just a quick question how wud i apply 'class incorrect-ans' to the label when user click the wrong option.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test, and it seems to work. http://jsbin.com/bavaxurinu/1/edit?html,console,output